# Adding a custom object to a Priority queue in Python

Tags: python

I want to add *Node* objects to Python's *PriorityQueue* in Python 2. The *Node* objects should be prioritized according to the val attribute:

```
class ListNode:
     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
         self.val = val
         self.next = next
```

I am not allowed to tamper with this *ListNode* class so I do not have the option to add the *__lt__* method to it.

Comment: are you solving a leetcode question? I remember this same class from one of the questions..

Comment: the way I did is use a global counter and on every heappush `i was using heapq`, I insert the counter value as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a tuple to put the priority and the object in the PriorityQueue.  Try:

```
pq = PriorityQueue()
ln2 = ListNode(2)
ln = ListNode(1, ln2)
pq.put((ln.val, ln))
pq.put((ln2.val, ln2))
```

Comment: I get the error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'ListNode' and 'ListNode'. But I am not allowed to temper with the ListNode class such that I can add the \_\_lt\_\_ method.

Comment: Hmm, it shouldn't be comparing ListNodes, but the int values.  What does your code look like?  Is the tuple in the correct order?

Comment: The problem occurs when I add a node whose value already exists in the priority queue. So it attempts to compare using the second element in the tuple. However, I want it to just add the new node (whose value is already in the queue) without worrying about the order relative to the other node with the same value.

Comment: So you can't temper with ListNode, can you temper with Priority Queue or create your own PQ implementation?  Alternatively you could use 3 values for the tuple (value, value2, ln) where value2  is some int that differentiates list nodes with equal values.  But you will run into the same issue if value2 is the same as some other.

Comment: The alternative with 3 values works well. I wish the built-in PriorityQueue would allow a comparison function as one of its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The PriorityQueue class sorts its objects as indicated by:

> The lowest valued entries are retrieved first (the lowest valued entry is the one returned by sorted(list(entries))[0]).

When this is called on your objects that don't have an __lt__ method, it throws a TypeError.

To circumvent this, object IDs can be used instead of adding the object to the PriorityQueue. Python object IDs are globally unique, can can be obtained by calling `id(object)`.

You can create a hashtable (dictionary) that has object ids as keys, and the object as the value.

```
pq = PriorityQueue()
list_node_A = ListNode(2)
list_node_B = ListNode(1)
for list_node in [list_node_A, list_node_B]:
    object_dictionary[id(list_node)] = list_node    # create id reference in dict
    pq.put((list_node.val, id(list_node))           # put into queue
list_node_id = pq.get()                             # get out of queue (id)
list_node = object_dictionary[list_node_id]         # get object from dict by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce another element to your tuple such that you avoid comparing ListNode. For instance, you could do the following:

```
pq = PriorityQueue()
ln2 = ListNode(2)
ln = ListNode(1, ln2)
pq.put((ln.val, pq.qsize(), ln))
pq.put((ln2.val, pq.qsize(), ln2))
```

For PriorityQueue, `qsize()` is implemented as `len(self.queue)` where `self.queue = []`. This way you are guaranteed to have a unique value before your `ListNode` objects that is comparable. The only caveat is that `qsize()` will acquire a mutex before returning the size, so you do suffer that overhead.